# Continue button does not close the box

Tags: javascript

So i have this site im creating and it has a box in the center of it that when i push continue in the bottom right hand corner I would like the box to disappear and display the site behind it.

How can I do this? I am not a strong coder, but with a little guidance I could probably do it. Thank you all in advance for your help.

I attached a pic in case my explanation wasnt good.( I guess i dont have enough of a reputation to do so) :(
Also not sure if i put this question in the right forum...

-Sa!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Post some code and error that you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do what you might be describing:

You'll need a `div` with an `id` attribute, and a button with an `id` also:

```
<div id='overlay'><button type='button' id='btncontinue'>Continue</button></div>
```

You can style it with CSS like this (maybe):

```
#overlay {
    background:black;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

You can toggle the overlay like this:

```
document.getElementById('btncontinue').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

---

Just for kicks, an interesting alternative way to get the width 100% and the height 100% is:

```
#overlay {
    background:black;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your response. I guess i need to learn my etiquette on here. I will definitely try this and let you know how it works out. Again thank you!

Comment: No worries, well said :) I'd say it's pretty standard etiquette on any  coding site, just FYI.  Hope the above can bump you in the right direction(s).